# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[Any]'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, database, uitableview

I'm getting the error with the following code in my `cellForRowAt` method:

```
self.db.collection("myCollection").document(self.currentUser!).updateData(["myArray":FieldValue.arrayRemove(myArray![indexPath.row])]).
```

The `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[Any]'` error is happening at `myArray![indexPath.row]`

My function is meant to remove a `String` value from `myArray`, so I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

I appreciate any help/guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayRemove` takes an array of values to be removed, you you'd want to use:

```
.arrayRemove([myArray![indexPath.row]])
```

*See the added brackets*

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

That being said, be aware that you're force unwrapping multiple things with `!` -- be aware that if one of these values is `nil`, your program will crash.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you!!